# Is there any way to put a message to AWS SQS without access & secret key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httprequest, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

We configured the EC2 instance which has IAM role with full permission for SQS and EC2. Is there any way to send a message to queue without any SDK/CLI Support of AWS? Only with Simple REST Call from EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question "*Is there any way to put a message to AWS SQS without access & secret key?*" is **YES**

When you use SDK/CLI from within EC2 then you can simply attach IAM role to EC2 that lets you communicate with your SQS. And then once you have that role correctly setup then  you can put a message to AWS SQS without access and secret key. And this is recommended.

The answer to question "*Is there any way to send a message to queue without any SDK/CLI Support of AWS? Only with Simple REST Call from EC2 instance?*" is **YES** as well.

For more details [check this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-making-api-requests.html).

But in that case (using Simple REST Call) you will have to [sign the request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use cURL to send a message to SQS.

```
curl -d "Action=SendMessage&Version=2011-10-01&MessageBody=example" <your queue url>
```

However, I highly recommend to use IAM roles to grant write/read access to your SQS.

Comment: Works only when the queue is permitted to be written from anywhere.